# NSWorkSpace import

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I call this line in my app:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:[LogUtilisateur singletonLogUtilisateur].cheminFichier withApplication:@"Mail"];
```

but when I compile, xcode said: NSWorkSpace undeclared.

There is a import or a special framework I must include to work with NSWorkSpace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This class belongs to AppKit framework. But it is available only for MacOS